# Cambiando presentacion de ListPreference

Tags: android

Estoy usando ListPreference para lanzar un menú de configuración y por estética me gustaría diferenciar el titulo del menu (Puerto serie) del resto de las opciones, ya sea cambiando el color del texto o cambiando el typeface a bold, pero cuando trato de hacer usando styles.xml se cambia todo, se puede hacer lo que estoy necesitando?, como?

Este es mi style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    <item name="android:editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/textAppearanceCustom</item>

</style>

<style name="textAppearanceCustom">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/AZUL</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>

</style>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que hacer un `layout` personalizado para esa pantalla que incluya un `TextView` con el título de las opciones y un `ListPreference`

Comment: Alguien me podria dar un ejemplo de como hacer un layout personalizado e integrarlo a un ListPreference